# Let $Y=e^X$ find probability function of $Y$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ a normal variable with expected value $4$and variance 1.

I need find the probability function of Y.

I know by definition, if $X$ is normal then the probability function of $X$ is

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\quad (x\in\mathbb{R}).$

Then, the probability function of $X$ is

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}\right)\quad (x\in\mathbb{R}).$

Now, for find the probability function of $Y$ if $Y=e^X$ then

$f(ln(y))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(ln(y)-4)^2}{2}\right)\quad $

Here, i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: It might be easier to determine the CDF of $Y$ and then take the derivative to obtain the density.

Comment: Look at [_log-normal_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this.
$$
\mathbb P(X \le a) = 
\int_{-\infty}^a\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}\right)dx\quad (a\in\mathbb{R})
\\
\mathbb P(X \le \log a) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\log a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}\right)dx\quad (a > 0)
\\
\mathbb P(\log Y \le \log a) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\log a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}\right)dx\quad (a > 0)
\\
\mathbb P(Y \le a) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\log a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}\right)dx\quad (a > 0)
$$
change variables, $x = \log y, dx = \frac{dy}{y}$
$$
\mathbb P(Y \le a) = 
\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{((\log y)-4)^2}{2}\right)\frac{dy}{y}\quad (a > 0)
$$
so the pdf for $Y$ is
$$
\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{((\log y)-4)^2}{2}\right)
\qquad (y > 0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct. We can take  advantage of the transformation formula
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|$$
In this case, $$Y=e^X\Rightarrow X=\text{ln}(Y) \ \ \ (Y>0)$$

It is also given that $$X\sim N(4,1)\Rightarrow f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\left({-\frac{(x-4)^2}{2}}\right)  \ \ \ \ \ \left(x\in(-\infty,\infty)\right)$$
Putting this information into the formula, we have
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=f_X(\text{ln}(y))\left|\frac{1}{y}\right| \\
&=\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{exp}\left({-\frac{(\text{ln}(y)-4)^2}{2}}\right) \ \ \ \ \ (y>0)
\end{align}
Hence the pdf of $Y$ is $$\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{exp}\left({-\frac{(\text{ln}(y)-4)^2}{2}}\right)\ \ \ \ \ (y>0)$$

Answer (score 0):

When you say the "probability function" I'm assuming you mean the probability density function.

Here's an approach: start with the cumulative distribution function.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(Y \leq y)
& = P(X \leq \log(y)) \\
& = \Phi(\log(y))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $ \Phi(\cdot) $ denotes the cumulative distribution function of a Normal(4, 1) random variable.

Then, we can obtain the density function by differentiating with
respect to $ y $.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d \Phi(\log(y))}{dy}
& = f(\log(y)) \frac{1}{y} \text{ by the chain rule} \\
& = \frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(\frac{-(\log(y) - 4)^2}{2})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $ f(x) $ is as you defined.

This you can verify is the log-normal pdf!